# How to combine 3 VBA variable into date datatype in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
'Dim two date variables 

Dim fromDate As Date
Dim toDate As Date

'Dim 4 integer variables   

Dim fromyear As Integer
Dim toyear As Integer
Dim frommonth As Integer
Dim ToMonth As Integer

'Store combo box value into these 4 integer variables 

fromyear = FromYearC.Value
frommonth = FromMonthC.Value
toyear = ToYearC.Value
ToMonth = ToMonthC.Value

'Now i want to combine these integer and store into fromDate and toDate

fromDate = WorksheetFunction.Date(fromyear, frommonth, 1)
toDate = WorksheetFunction.Date(toyear, ToMonth, 31)
```

> ERROR:
>   Object don't support this method

***Is it unable to put VBA variable into excel worksheetfunction?***

## update SQL

```
  sSQLString = "SELECT  officer ,NULL, SUM(IIF( isnumeric(mkt) = true and Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and Outcome= 'C', Totalmin, 0 )/468) ," & _
 " SUM(IIF( isnumeric(Non) = true and Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and Outcome= 'C', Totalmin, 0 )/468) ,NULL ,NULL , " & _
 "IIF(ISNULL(sum(mkt)),0,sum(mkt)),Sum(Non),sum(ICP),(sum(mkt)+Sum(Non)+sum(ICP) )  ,NULL,NULL,NULL,count(IIF( Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' ," & _
 "Totalmin, NULL )),NULL,count(IIF(  Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and  (Outcome ='C' OR Outcome='D'OR Outcome='O') , Totalmin, NULL )),NULL,SUM(IIF( Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' ,Totalmin, 0 )),NULL,SUM(IIF( Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and (Outcome ='C' OR Outcome='D') ,Totalmin, 0 )) From  (select officer ,rank ,year ,month ,day , survey ,activity ,outcome ,mkt,non,totalmin,ICP ,date from [2014$] UNION ALL  select officer ,rank ,year ,month ,day , survey ,activity ,outcome ,mkt,non,totalmin,ICP ,date from [2015$]  UNION ALL  select officer ,rank ,year ,month ,day , survey ,activity ,outcome ,mkt,non,totalmin,ICP ,date from [2016$] UNION ALL  select officer ,rank ,year ,month ,day , survey ,activity ,outcome ,mkt,non,totalmin,ICP ,date from [2017$])as table3 " & _
 "where officer is not null and officer <> '' and officer <> ' '  and date >= #" & fromDate & "# AND date<=#" & toDate & "# group by officer"
```

Here is sSQLString where `fromDate = #6/1/2016#` and `toDate = #7/1/2016#`:

```
SELECT  officer ,NULL, SUM(IIF( isnumeric(mkt) = true and Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and Outcome= 'C', Totalmin, 0 )/468) , SUM(IIF( isnumeric(Non) = true and Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and Outcome= 'C', Totalmin, 0 )/468) ,NULL ,NULL , IIF(ISNULL(sum(mkt)),0,sum(mkt)),Sum(Non),sum(ICP),(sum(mkt)+Sum(Non)+sum(ICP) )  ,NULL,NULL,NULL,count(IIF( Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' ,Totalmin, NULL )),NULL,count(IIF(  Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and  (Outcome ='C' OR Outcome='D'OR Outcome='O') , Totalmin, NULL )),NULL,SUM(IIF( Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' ,Totalmin, 0 )),NULL,SUM(IIF( Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and (Outcome ='C' OR Outcome='D') ,Totalmin, 0 )) From  (select officer ,rank ,year ,month ,day , survey ,activity ,outcome ,mkt,non,totalmin,ICP ,date from [2014$] UNION ALL  select officer ,rank ,year ,month ,day , survey ,activity ,outcome ,mkt,non,totalmin,ICP ,date from [2015$]  UNION ALL  select officer ,rank ,year ,month ,day , survey ,activity ,outcome ,mkt,non,totalmin,ICP ,date from 
[2016$] UNION ALL  select officer ,rank ,year ,month ,day , survey ,activity ,outcome ,mkt,non,totalmin,ICP ,date from [2017$])as table3 where officer is not null and officer <> '' and officer <> ' '  and date >= #6/1/2016# AND date<=#7/1/2016# group by officer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the VBA doesn;t make the `WorksheetFunction.Date` available to use.

With the help of Rory we established the proper way to assign the date values is like this:

```
fromDate = DateSerial(fromyear, frommonth, 1)
toDate = DateSerial(toyear, ToMonth + 1, 0)
```

The proper way to use dates in an sql string is to surround them in hashes #.

WHERE tabledate >= #" & fromDate & "# AND tabledate<=#" & toDate & "#"

If tabledate is a DateTime field then you would need to modify your code to reflect dates `<toDate + 1` intstead of `<=toDate`.  This way you'll get the records including `toDate + TimeValue`.

Here is the VBA DateTime modifications

```
fromDate = DateSerial(fromyear, frommonth, 1)
toDate = DateSerial(toyear, ToMonth + 1, 1)
```

This is the new SQL string

WHERE tabledate >= #" & fromDate & "# AND tabledate<#" & toDate & "#"

The best way to test the query is to `Debug.Print` it to the immediate window.  Next you'll copy the query and run it in the actual database.  From there you can tweak the SQL. Finally you need to modify your VBA code to reflect the any changes in the SQL.

Comment: @in my perception , the assignment should be right .However ,`  fromDate = DateSerial(fromyear, frommonth, 1)
   toDate = DateSerial(toyear, ToMonth + 1, 0) /////where officer is not null and officer <> '' and officer <> ' '  and date >= #" & fromDate & "# AND date<=#" & toDate & "# group by officer" ` The SQL result is not accurate .The sql result numbers  now are much smaller  than the real result

Comment: Is tabledate a DateTime field?

Comment: originally in Gernal datatype in excel . Now i change to date field .Still not okay .Result same as orginal

Comment: Can you `Debug.Print` the query, so that I can see the actual SQL?

Comment: please see #update SQL ,the SQL is too long . running the sql will output on a new worksheet  .Hence , i guess `debug.rpint` without output

Comment: What I wanted was the actual query string.  I added it to your answer.  If there are any time values in the tabledate field, you'll need to make the modifications in my answer.  There is no way that I can test your query.  You should test each select statement independently.  This might give you a clue to the missing records.

Comment: Do u mean that there may be some time value exist in my table_date?  I guarantee there is no time value there as i make the time_date by combining the day, month, year field using date(). Therefore ,all table_date should be in d/m/year format , eg. 21/4/2016
,22/6/2015,30/10/2014

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `WorksheetFunction` when you can use native VBA functions instead. The [DateSerial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264202.aspx) function does in code what Excel's `Date` does in a worksheet:

Change this:

> ```
> fromDate = WorksheetFunction.Date(fromyear, frommonth, 1)
> toDate = WorksheetFunction.Date(toyear, ToMonth, 31)
> ```

To:

```
fromDate = DateSerial(fromyear, frommonth, 1)
toDate = DateSerial(toyear, ToMonth, 31)
```

Mind the hard-coded `31` here, not all months have 31 days.

Comment: `toDate = DateSerial(toyear, ToMonth, 31)` will return the wrong date if the month doesn't have 31 days.  `toDate = DateSerial(toyear, ToMonth + 1, -1) will return the correct last day of the month.

Comment: @ThomasInzina you are right, there are many possible errors that might occure here, like inserting a value larger than 12 to `ToMonth` , I hope the user know what he's doing :)

Comment: Still 31 is hard coded and will return `3/2/2016` for `DateSerial(2016,3,31)` where as `DateSerial(2016,2 + 1,-1)` will return `2/28/2016`.

Comment: @Thomas Inzina in fact i want to set the sql condition : `where tabledate >= "& fromDate &" and tabledate<="&toDate&"` .But i still got syntax error

Comment: @ThomasInzina It should actually be `DateSerial(toyear, ToMonth + 1, 0)` rather than -1 by the way to get the last day of the month (2016 is a leap year)

Comment: I messed up on the DateSerial.  `toDate = DateSerial(toyear, ToMonth + 1, 0)`  will return the correct last day of the month.  `FromYearC.Value` would equal a 4 digit year?

Comment: Lol..I forgot the actual syntax and that this is a leap year.  Thanks @Rory

Answer (score 0):

Use the worksheet function `EoMonth` as in *end-of-month* instead of hardcoding a date that may result in error.

```
Sub e(fromyear As Long, frommonth As Long, toyear As Long, tomonth As Long)
    Dim fromdate As Date, todate As Date
    fromdate = DateSerial(fromyear, frommonth, 1)
    todate = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(DateSerial(toyear, tomonth, 1), 0)
    MsgBox Format(fromdate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " to " & Format(todate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
End Sub

Sub f()
    Call e(2011, 11, 2016, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: You should change `Sub e` to `Function EoMonth` and have it return the value of `WorksheetFunction.EoMonth`.  I would also change `Sub f` to   `Sub Example()                                                                                                Msgbox EoMonth(2011, 11, 2016, 2)                                                           End Sub`