# The SQL result is inaccurate because of wrong SQL date comparison setting

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

I run SQL in excel using ADO in excel-VBA. And the results are displayed on an excel worksheet.

There is a field called Date in worksheet 2014,2015,2016,2017

the data example :2/1/2014,7/1/2014,23/10/2014

this field datatype is in day/month/year .And date is combined by =DATE(cell1,cell2,cell3)  -year,month ,day .The date in tables should all be purely date as i combine 3 cells (year ,month , date )into 1 field (date)

```
'Dim two date variables 

Dim fromDate As Date
Dim toDate As Date

'Dim 4 integer variables   

Dim fromyear As Integer
Dim toyear As Integer
Dim frommonth As Integer
Dim ToMonth As Integer

'add combobox value
With FromYearC
.AddItem 2014
.AddItem 2015
.AddItem 2016
.AddItem 2017
End With

'add combobox value 
With FromMonthC
.AddItem 1
.AddItem 2
.AddItem 3
.AddItem 4
.AddItem 5
.AddItem 6
.AddItem 7
.AddItem 8
.AddItem 9
.AddItem 10
.AddItem 11
.AddItem 12
End With

'Store combo box value into these 4 integer variables 

fromyear = FromYearC.Value
frommonth = FromMonthC.Value
toyear = ToYearC.Value
ToMonth = ToMonthC.Value

'Now i want to combine these variables and store into fromDate and toDate
fromDate = DateSerial(fromyear, frommonth, 1)
toDate = DateSerial(toyear, ToMonth + 1, 1)

'it is still wrong , no matter orginal date format or new date format"dd/mm/yyyy"
  fromDate = Format(fromDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    toDate = Format(toDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

VBA user interface:
[image]
Now i want to set the date range between fromdate and todate (both inclusive )

i build the SQL  reference to :
[How to combine 3 VBA variable into date datatype in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497479/how-to-combine-3-vba-variable-into-date-datatype-in-vba)

```
 ' This is the new SQL string

WHERE date >= #" & fromdate & "# AND date<#" & toDate & "#"
```

## problem:

Now the SQL result is totally wrong (still have output) .I guess the SQL where-clause has something wrong . As the SQL is right originally ,the SQL become wrong with the where-date selection clause .

Or i tried to use where-between clause .this is still wrong .

```
date between  #" & fromDate & "#  and  #" & toDate & "#
```

The full SQL is here but i think it is too long

```
    SELECT  officer ,NULL, SUM(IIF( isnumeric(mkt) = true and Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and Outcome= 'C', Totalmin, 0 )/468) , SUM(IIF( isnumeric(Non) = true and Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and Outcome= 'C', Totalmin, 0 )/468) ,NULL ,NULL , IIF(ISNULL(sum(mkt)),0,sum(mkt)),Sum(Non),sum(ICP),(sum(mkt)+Sum(Non)+sum(ICP) )  ,NULL,NULL,NULL,count(IIF( Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' ,Totalmin, NULL )),NULL,count(IIF(  Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and  (Outcome ='C' OR Outcome='D'OR Outcome='O') , Totalmin, NULL )),NULL,SUM(IIF( Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' ,Totalmin, 0 )),NULL,SUM(IIF( Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and (Outcome ='C' OR Outcome='D') ,Totalmin, 0 )) From  (select officer ,rank ,year ,month ,day , survey ,activity ,outcome ,mkt,non,totalmin,ICP ,date from [2014$] UNION ALL  select officer ,rank ,year ,month ,day , survey ,activity ,outcome ,mkt,non,totalmin,ICP ,date from [2015$]  UNION ALL  select officer ,rank ,year ,month ,day , survey ,activity ,outcome ,mkt,non,totalmin,ICP ,date from 
[2016$] UNION ALL  select officer ,rank ,year ,month ,day , survey ,activity ,outcome ,mkt,non,totalmin,ICP ,date from [2017$])as table3 where officer is not null and officer <> '' and officer <> ' '  and  date >= #" & fromDate & "# AND date<#" & toDate & "#" group by officer
```

## update

I try to use hard code

```
 and date >= #1-3-2016# AND date<#31-3-2016#
```

to test the SQL .

It fails like the original SQL . It can output the results but the result is wrong .

I guess is it related to the UNION ALL ?
As i join all 4 tables records to become a big  table .

## Update 2

I believe it is not related to UNION ALL.
As the excel column date is combined in 3 cells - year ,month ,day , i copy and paste the value again .The SQL results have changes .However , the result is still incorrect .

Then i tried to use hard code to test .
For example , i try to select the record on March 2016.
Using this where clause :

```
and month=3 and year=2016
```

It is OKAY .

Then i tried to use this where statement below .This is not OKAY .

```
date >= #2016-03-01# AND date<#2016-04-01#
```

Then i believe it should be the date datatype problem in either excel or VBA .

Then , i tried to do these testing below :

For Excel , the original datatype is date .i change to string , numeric ,general... Not okay

Date sample :6/1/2016
String sample:42375
numeric sample :42375.00

For VBA , i tried to swap the month and day . --> #2016-01-03# Still Not OKAY

Comment: What is your region date setting dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: @Jules the date in excel is dd/mm/yyyy . I change to dd/mm/yyyy for the VBA date variable .However , it is still wrong . `fromDate = Format(fromDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    toDate = Format(toDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")`

Comment: Why are you using `date` as a column name?

Comment: @KyloRen As i have to combine 4 tables records into a big table , I can let the user select from a specific period of date ,like one month , one year ,etc..

Comment: You should not be using that as a name , it could cause problems.

Comment: @KyloRen i change date to tabledate. Problems still happen

Comment: What is the error saying about the SQL statement?

Comment: You have to put conditions on both select statements.

Comment: @kyloRen No error . Just inaccurate SQL results

Comment: @Jules   i join 4 tables by UNION ALL . and where .....   .Even though i tried to use hard code ,it is still not okay.

Comment: I check your sql and it looks file.  UNION ALL will return duplicate values.  If you don't want duplicate use UNION.  I would remove the where condition and see if the returned rows are what you expect.

Comment: @Jules I tried to copy and paste the tabledate into value only (not formula) in excel .The SQL results have big different .However , the result is still wrong(even hard code) .Now i believe UNION ALL is fine . The problem should be on excel date format or SQL date range setting

Comment: I created 4 tables with dummy data. First column Date, Second Column Numbers.  I've used union query using date format "dd mmm yyyy" and it works as expected.  Is your date format string or date (numeric)?

Comment: @Jules  tried  string ,date , numeric ... still not okay . See UPDATE2 (here is my progress)

Comment: Unless I can get your data, I am out of idea.

Comment: @Jules Anyway thanks

Comment: @Jules problem solved . one of my table[2017$] is empty . i add one row of record into 2017 . The SQL result is okay then .Dunno the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create String variables for the fromDate and toDate dates and pass them to the WHERE clause. I suggest you use ISO date format. In addition to that to avoid problems with the column name date let's try enclosing the date column in the square brackets (do this also for the unioned tables), like this:

```
  fromDateStr = Format(fromDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    toDateStr = Format(toDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")

"WHERE [date] >= #" & fromDateStr & "# AND [date]<#" & toDateStr & "#"
```

On a side note, what happens with this expression `DateSerial(toyear, ToMonth + 1, 1)` when the toMonth is December? Shouldn't you use [DateAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcxe65wz(v=vs.90).aspx) function?

```
toDate = DateAdd("m", 1, DateSerial(toyear, ToMonth, 1))
```

Comment: Additional info, to get last day of the month DateAdd("d",-1,DateAdd("m", 1, "1 jan 2016"))

Comment: Alternatively use Format(fromDate, "dd mmm yyyy")

Comment: Is it possible that the date is right, but when you present it on the screen in Excel the date format is wrong?

Comment: @Monchhichi Try hard coding the date range and see if it returns the expected result.

Comment: @cha i tried `and date >= #1-3-2016# AND date<#31-3-2016#`   already wrong  .I don;t know what is the problem

Comment: @cha i guess it may be caused by UNION ALL? As i union all 4 tables records to become a big table  .

Comment: Can you try `date >= #2016-03-01# AND date<#2016-04-01#`?

Comment: @cha tried , still not okay . See UPDATE2 (here is my progress)

Comment: @cha problem solved . one of my table[2017$] is empty . i add one row of record into [2017$] . The SQL result is okay then .Dunno the reason