# How to select the date between A & B accurately?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

This question continues the discussion from [The SQL result is inaccurate because of wrong SQL date comparison setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560620/the-sql-result-is-inaccurate-because-of-wrong-sql-date-comparison-setting?noredirect=1#comment64549078_38560620)

I run SQL in excel using ADO in excel-VBA, and the results are displayed on an excel worksheet.

There is a field called "Date" in worksheet 2014,2015,2016,2017

The data example: 2/1/2014,7/1/2014,23/10/2014

This field datatype is in day/month/year, and date is combined by =DATE(cell1,cell2,cell3) - year, month, day. The date in tables should all be purely date as I combine 3 cells (year, month, date) into 1 field (date)

---

Now, I want to set the date range between fromdate and todate (both inclusive)

```
 ' This SQL select the date between date-VARIABLE: fromdate & toDate

WHERE date >= #" & fromdate & "# AND date<#" & toDate & "#"
```

Full SQL here:

```
SELECT  officer ,NULL, SUM(IIF( isnumeric(mkt) = true and Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and Outcome= 'C', Totalmin, 0 )/468) , SUM(IIF( isnumeric(Non) = true and Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and Outcome= 'C', Totalmin, 0 )/468) ,NULL ,NULL , IIF(ISNULL(sum(mkt)),0,sum(mkt)),Sum(Non),sum(ICP),(sum(mkt)+Sum(Non)+sum(ICP) )  ,NULL,NULL,NULL,count(IIF( Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' ,Totalmin, NULL )),NULL,count(IIF(  Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and  (Outcome ='C' OR Outcome='D'OR Outcome='O') , Totalmin, NULL )),NULL,SUM(IIF( Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' ,Totalmin, 0 )),NULL,SUM(IIF( Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and (Outcome ='C' OR Outcome='D') ,Totalmin, 0 ))
From  (
    select officer ,rank ,year ,month ,day , survey ,activity ,outcome ,mkt,non,totalmin,ICP ,date 
    from [2014$] 
    UNION ALL  
    select officer ,rank ,year ,month ,day , survey ,activity ,outcome ,mkt,non,totalmin,ICP ,date 
    from [2015$]  
    UNION ALL  
    select officer ,rank ,year ,month ,day , survey ,activity ,outcome ,mkt,non,totalmin,ICP ,date 
    from [2016$] 
    UNION ALL  
    select officer ,rank ,year ,month ,day , survey ,activity ,outcome ,mkt,non,totalmin,ICP ,date 
    from [2017$]
)as table3 
where officer is not null and officer <> '' and officer <> ' '  
and  date >= #" & fromDate & "# AND date<#" & toDate & "#" 
group by officer
```

Then I find the SQL result is working, but the result is inaccurate.

---

Later, I try to test in hard code. For example, I try to select the record on March 2016. Using this where clause:

```
where month=3 and year=2016
```

It is OKAY.

Then, I tried to use these where statement below. They are not OKAY.

```
where date >= #2016-03-01# AND date<#2016-04-01#
```

`where date between #2016-03-01# and  #2016-04-01#`

Then, I believe it should be the date datatype problem in either excel or VBA.

Then, I tried to do these testing below:

For Excel, the original datatype is date. I change to string, numeric, general... Not okay

```
Date sample: 6/1/2016 
String sample: 42375 
Numeric sample: 42375.00
```

For VBA, I tried to swap the month and day. --> #2016-01-03# Still Not OKAY

More information can refer to [The SQL result is inaccurate because of wrong SQL date comparison setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560620/the-sql-result-is-inaccurate-because-of-wrong-sql-date-comparison-setting?noredirect=1#comment64549078_38560620)

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try

For the `fromDate` suffix a time point of zero and for the `toDate` suffix a time point to the end of the date.

```
fromDate = 01/01/2016 00:00:00
  toDate = 02/02/2016 23:59:59
```

Also, give the month as the 3 letter option if possible, I now use this in all my work as a lot goes over to the U.S. and they do MM/DD/YYYY as opposed to me in the U.K. who uses DD/MM/YYYY. By outputting 01/Jan/2016 there is no confusion over which is the month field by either user or the system.

Comment: `and date >= #01/March/2016 00:00:00# and  date <#01/Apr/2016 00:00:00#` i tried to test in hardcode .The result is not correcet